# Doctors and Insurance Networks

Tags: medical

Where can I find a database of doctors and accepted insurances? The closest I've gotten is https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/ but while that includes what looks like insurers under the "identifiers" property, it doesn't mention specifically which plans are accepted. So it will list:

```
"identifiers": [
    {
        "code": "01",
        "desc": "Other",
        "identifier": "909101",
        "issuer": "PHYSICANS HEALTH",
        "state": "NY"
    },
    {
        "code": "01",
        "desc": "Other",
        "identifier": "010126174NY01",
        "issuer": "ANTHEM HEALTH",
        "state": "NY"
    },
    {
        "code": "01",
        "desc": "Other",
        "identifier": "1000016207",
        "issuer": "AFFINITY HEALTH PLAN",
        "state": "NY"
    },
    {
        "code": "05",
        "desc": "MEDICAID",
        "identifier": "00296768",
        "issuer": "",
        "state": "NY"
    },
    {
        "code": "01",
        "desc": "Other",
        "identifier": "0611880",
        "issuer": "UNITED HEALTH CARE",
        "state": "NY"
    },
    {
        "code": "01",
        "desc": "Other",
        "identifier": "541254",
        "issuer": "AETNA SPECIALIST",
        "state": "NY"
    }
]
```

I know he is registered with Anthem Health but not whether he is part of the HMO network or some other network under Anthem. Also, the docs mention the "identifiers" property is limited to 50 items, what if all identifiers exceed 50?

There has to be a better way to get network information by provider. I could pay thousands a month to license the data if I had that kind of budget, but I don't, perhaps $100 or less per month but not what I've been getting quoted. Where could I find that kind of information without paying an exorbitant licensing fee?